# RSpec: assert message calls on stub/spy arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

Is there an RSpec way to do assertions on the return value of arguments passed to other objects?

Say I'm expecting `Checker#notify` to call `Mailer.send(report)`, and I want to assert that `report.errors_count` will return `2` ?

I got very close with this:

```
expect(Mailer).to have_received(:send).with(hash_including(:errors_count => 2))
```

But that will only work with a hash. What if I'm passing a `PORO` or a `Struct`. `duck_type()` also comes pretty close but just asserts the method is defined, not its return value (which is kind of the important part here).

PS: Ideally I'd like to avoid doing something like this:

```
expected_report = Report.new.tap{|r| r.errors_count = 2}
expect(Mailer).to have_received(:send).with(expected_report)
```

1. I'd rather test interfaces and not depend on the actual class used to generate the report (quack quack)
2. If `Checker` adds other states I don't care about, this will break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! You can pass a block to `receive`. It takes the arguments passed to the method, so you can test anything on them:

```
expect(Mailer).to receive(:send_mail) do |report|
  expect(report.error_count).to be(2)
end
```

*Edit: This doesn't seem to work with the spy (`have_received`) version. The test will be green but the block won't be evaluated.*

Answer (score 1):

Try Rspec's [#and_call_original](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method)